# Regex - match trailing character only if zero or many group matches

Tags: regex

I can't figure out how not have my regex match in the scenario where the zero or many group does not capture anything.

My regex I have come up with now
`^\.?([a-zA-Z0-9]*)_?(foobar)\.txt$`

Test cases:

```
sometext_foobar.txt <- Should match and return 'sometext' in a group
_foobar.txt      <--- I want it to NOT match on this
.foobar.txt      <---- Works match group (foobar)
.bcd_foobar.txt  <---- Works match group (bcd) and (foobar)
```

Basically if `([a-zA-Z0-9]*)` doesn't match, then do not allow an underscore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write the pattern maching 1+ times [a-zA-Z0-9]+ followed by an underscore ,and make that whole part optional.

```
^\.?([a-zA-Z0-9]+_)?(foobar)\.txt$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jVMv41/1)

Note that you have 2 capture groups, if you want a match only:

```
^\.?(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+_)?foobar\.txt$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/s9R1Q8/1)

Comment: Thanks that helps, I actually missed a test case I wanted this to work on where the capture group makes more sense. I added it in the question.
edit: the only thing that doesn't work is in your first example, the _ is included in the match group. I would like to not include it.

Comment: I was able to modify yours a bit and get it to work for my cases. Thanks
`^\.?(?:([a-zA-Z0-9]+)_)?foobar\.txt$`